# Scala Option Equivalent to callIfNotEmpty

Tags: scala, option-type

Is there any Option function equivalent to:

```
def callIfNotEmpty[T](option: Option[T], fun: (T) => Unit): Unit = option match {
    case Some(x) => fun(x)
    case None =>
}
```

That could be called as:

```
option.callIfNotEmpty((optionValue) => fun(optionValue))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `foreach`.  For example:

```
option.foreach(println)
```

From  the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option):

> `final def foreach[U](f: (A) ⇒ U): Unit`
>
> Apply the given procedure `f` to the option's value, if it is nonempty.

There's even a comment at the top of the `Option` code:

> The most idiomatic way to use an `scala.Option` instance is to treat it as a collection or monad and use `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, or `foreach`

Recall that an `Option` can be implicitly converted to an `Iterable`, so anything you usually to on collections is available to you!

Comment: Beautifully Simple.  Thanks.

Comment: I also like to use the `fold` method on `Option` instances for cases where you need an expression to return a default value when the `Option` is empty, but you want to return a function result for the non-empty case.